# passing data from UITabBarView Class to sub class of UIViewController using swift

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, xcode7, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to pass data from my TabViewClass to sub Class of its Tab ViewController 
Here is my TabBar Class

class TabBarController : UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate{

```
var unitId : Int = 0;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("TabBarVC Called")
    unitId = 10;
    print("Unit Id = \(unitId)")

    self.delegate = self;
```

}
}

after running this viewDidLoad() my sub class of first Tab Bar automatically called its viewDidLoad() .. how can I share my major Tab Bar Controller class data into its sub Tab class (View Controllers) .. using swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know it is better way or not, I have passed the data this way:

```
class TabBarController : UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate{
var unitId : Int = 0;

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
print("TabBarVC Called")
unitId = 10;
print("Unit Id = \(unitId)")

self.delegate = self;

//Pass data to all tab controller
let MovementRepVC: MovementRep = self.viewControllers![0] as! MovementRep
MovementRepVC.id = self.unitId

let secondVC: UIViewController = self.viewControllers![1] as! UIViewController
secondVC.data = self.myData

} }
```

Hope It will help you.

Comment: firstVC .. not accept my ViewController class Variable

Comment: class MovementRep : UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{  var id : Int = 0  } .. in this class i want to receive id.. my first tab bar controller class

Comment: @zeeshannazakat for that you have to modify the code like this : 
let MovementRepVC: MovementRep = self.viewControllers![0] as! MovementRep
MovementRepVC.yourData = self.dataToShare

Comment: the above code give me this exception : UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
 VC segue called
Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x110e7d5d8) to 'VITS.MovementRep' (0x10efa92d0).

Comment: /Users/Irfan/Documents/My ISO APPS/VITS/VITS/TabBarController.swift:38:9: Instance member 'unitID' cannot be used on type 'MovementRep'

Comment: i have edited the answer. Now you will get the unitId value in MovementRepVC as id.